# tf.decode_raw and tf.reshape using different image size

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'am using the following code to generate tfrecords file.

```
  def generate_tfrecords(data_path, labels, name):
      """Converts a dataset to tfrecords."""
      filename = os.path.join(args.tfrecords_path, name + '.tfrecords')
      writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)
for index, data in enumerate(data_path):
      with tf.gfile.GFile(data, 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
        print(len(encoded_jpg))   # 17904
      encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
      image = pil.open(encoded_jpg_io)
      image = np.asarray(image)
      print(image.shape)    # 112*112*3
      example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'height': _int64_feature(int(image.shape[0])),
        'width': _int64_feature(int(image.shape[1])),
        'depth': _int64_feature(int(3)),
        'label': _int64_feature(int(labels[index])),
        'image_raw': _bytes_feature(encoded_jpg)}))
      writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
```

On the above code, the `encoded_jpg` have length `17904`, and the image have shape `112*112*3` which is not consistent.

When I'am parsing the tfrecords using the following code:

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):
     features = {'height':  tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0),
           'width': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0),
           'depth': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0),
           'label': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0),
           'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value="")}
     parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
     height = tf.cast(parsed_features["height"], tf.int32)  # 112
     width = tf.cast(parsed_features["width"], tf.int32)    # 112
     depth = tf.cast(parsed_features["depth"], tf.int32)   #3
     label = parsed_features['label']
     img = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['image_raw'], tf.uint8, little_endian=True)
     img = tf.reshape(img, [height, width, depth])
     return img, label
```

When I using the above code, I got the following errors:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 17904 values, but the requested shape has 37632
 [[Node: Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_UINT8, Tshape=DT_INT32](DecodeRaw, Reshape/shape)]]
 [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,?,?,?], [?]], output_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator)]]
```

How could I solve this problems. The image type is `png`, and `37632=112*112*3`. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the image type is PNG? The code mentions `jpg`, and it looks like the `encoded_jpg` is a raw image. The error message suggests that one of the raw images has a different size from the value that was encoded in the `height` and `depth` fields... is it possible that you have different-sized images in your dataset?

Answer (score 7):

Use [decode_jpeg](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_jpeg) instead of decode_raw

Comment: you saved the day (several days)!